# Java: removing word from a list

Tags: java, arraylist

I am currently working on making a vocable test were you can make your own vocables and their translation. I have faced a problem were I do not know how to make an option were you have different translations to pick from.

```
  public static void WritingYourVocables(List<VocableList> data) {

  String antal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Write the numbers of vocables you want to have");
  int temp  = Integer.parseInt(antal);

  for (int i = 0; i < temp; i++) {

     String Vocable = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Write a vocable");
     String Translation = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Write the translation for the vocable");

     data.add(new VocableTest(Vocable, Translation));

  }            
  }//WritingYourVocables ends
```

The method above is the the method were you write the numbers of vocables you want to have in your test, then you write your vocables and their translation.

```
  public static void PlayWithAlternatives(List<Alternatives> data) {

  int a = data.size();

  for (int n = 0; n < a; n++) {

     int Translate2;
     int Translate3;

     int Translate1 = (int)(Math.random() * data.size()) ;

     do {
         Translate2 = (int)(Math.random() * data.size()) ;

     }while (Translate1 == Translate2);

     do{
         Translate3 = (int)(Math.random() * data.size()) ;

     }while (Translate1 == Translate3 || Translate2 == Translate3);


        int answer [] = {Translate1, Translate2, Translate3};

        int Right = (int)(Math.random() * 3) ;


        int choice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is the translation of the vocable? " + 
                                                               data.get(answer[Right]).getVocable() +
                                                               "\n1: " + data.get(Translate1).getTranslation() + 
                                                               "\n2: " + data.get(Translate2).getTranslation() + 
                                                               "\n3: " + data.get(Translate3).getTranslation()));                                                             
           switch(choice){

              case 1:

                 if (answer[Right] == Translate1){

                    data.remove(?);

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Right");

                 }else{ JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong");
                 }

              break;

              case 2:

                 if (answer[Right] == Translate2){

                    data.remove(?);

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Right");

                 }else{ JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wring");
                 }


              break;

              case 3:

                 if (answer[Right] == Translate3){

                    data.remove(?);

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Right");
                 }else{ JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong");
                 }

              break;

              default:
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Wrong choice!");                                           

           }        
  }

  }//PlayingWithAlternatives ends
```

The method above is a method for playing with different alternatives to the translation for a random generated vocable. If the player picks the right alternative, the vocable that the alternative is connected with is supposed to be deleted. To remove the vocable I use "data.remove()", the problem is that I do not know what to write in the brackets to remove the vocable.

Please help

Comment: It is either the index of the thing you want to remove, or the object you want to remove. It looks like `Translate`, `Translate2` and `Translate3` are indexes into the list - so, `data.remove(Translate)` (or whichever variable).

Comment: You should try to follow java naming conventions: variables and methods should start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: What is Translate in data.remove(Translate) ?

Comment: Sorry. I meant `Translate1`.

Answer (score 3):

There are better ways to handle your design but as far as your question is concerned just remove the vocable you asked in the first place.

```
data.remove(answer[Right]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove elements from ArrayList :

You use :

```
arrlist.remove(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter of `List.remove` is either the index of the thing you want to remove, or the object you want to remove.

It looks like `Translate1`, `Translate2` and `Translate3` are indexes into the list - so call

```
data.remove(Translate1); // or whichever variable is correct.
```

---

You can make life easier for yourself if you put your `TranslateN` variables in an array:

```
int[] Translate = new int[3];
```

So, replace every occurrence of `Translate1` with `Translate[0]`, `Translate2` with `Translate[1]` etc.

Then, instead of the `switch` with almost identical handling of the 3 cases, you can simply use:

```
if (answer[Right] == Translate[choice-1]){
  data.remove(Translate[choice-1]);
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Right");
} else {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong");
}
```

---

You should also watch out for the infinite loop in the code, when you have fewer than 3 choices left: you can't pick 3 different values for the `Translate` variables if there are only 2 possible values.